# Unit test comparing response data raises TypeError

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write some unit tests for the example flaskr application.  I want to check if a specific string is in the response.  I keep getting a `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.  Why am I getting this error and how should I fix it?

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_empty_db (__main__.FlaskrTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_flaskr.py", line 31, in test_empty_db
    assert 'No entries here so far' in rv.data
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response data from the test client is bytes, not unicode, data.  In Python 3, this means you need to decode the data to compare it to a string, or compare it to a bytestring instead.

```
# compare bytes
assert b'No entries so far' in rv.data

# or decode to string
assert 'No entries so far' in rv.data.decode('utf8')
```